# How to remove doubled y-scrolling without content hidden?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

In laravel 5.8 / bootstrap 4.1 app I have pages with doubled y scrolling : https://prnt.sc/10jf83i
and I try to remove scrolling of the page(internal scrolling)

In app/views/layout/member.blade.php I have :

```
  <body>
    @include('elements.member_header')
    @yield('content')
    @include('elements.member_footer')
    <script> public(); </script>
    @yield('scripts')
  </body>
```

and in page.blade.php :

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('title', $title)
@section('description', $description)
@section('content')
<div class="member-wrapper" id="member-content">
    @include('elements.member_sidebar')
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="single-page">
            <div class="pages-heading">
                <h2>@lang('member.profile')</h2>
            </div>
```

If I try to salve with definition :

Then bottom of the page is hidden in case in dynamic content of the page is big in height.

Any hints if there is a way to salve it ?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not Laravel question. This is CSS / Bootstrap question. You should provide actual rendered HTML piece. Nobody can know how your page looks from this and how that bug looks

Comment: Or you can share the actual website url so I can look into your problem.

Comment: Can you paste the generated html and css somewhere like https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set content wrapper to have no height limit.

I cannot see from your code how it's being limited but I think setting height and max-height to auto should work.

depending on the specificity of the existing rules you may need to use !important to override.

```
.content-wrapper{
   height:auto !important;
   max-height:none !important;
}
```

#### Edit:

I just checked and noticed you just need to remove or overwrite the height in the `.member-wrapper`

```
.member-wrapper {
   height: auto;
}
```

[image: remove this height]

Comment: I tried to modify class definition but no success, still 2 scrollbars.
But in th console of my browser I see property max-height is not valid : https://imgur.com/a/ViPO919
Could you please take a look ?

Comment: sorry, the max-height value should be none instead of auto. I updated the answer

Comment: I appplied your changes, but design of the page become broken. Could you please take a look ?

Comment: I cannot even register in your platform. I get php error.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the html and css by doing "save page " in the browser

Comment: Thanks!, looks like it work ok. Please give me some time to test it more and set salved to this branch

Comment: @mstdmstd I see you applied this on you site and it did fix the double scroll bar issue. would you be so kind as to mark my answer as accepted?